# How do I keep my Android notification displayed until my app is closed?

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I've been developing for Android for awhile but this is my first shot at notifications.  I've got my notification setup as described in the Android SDK tutorial, but I can't figure out how to keep the notification displayed until my app is closed.  I want to disable that little minus sign at the end of the notification.  I don't want my notification to disappear when a user clicks it.  I would think there would be a notification flag...  but I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm developing on Android SDK 2.2.  I know this is a simple question, and I apologize if this answer is already on here... I wasn't able to find exactly what I was looking for.

```
    // Create notification manager
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Ready", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    // Make a notification
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Ready", "Select to manage your settings", contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).  Also try removing FLAG_NO_CLEAR and FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL if they are part of the defaults.

Comment: I am officially guilty of re-posting a question that has my answer: 

[link to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983032/how-to-get-a-permanent-application-notifier-in-the-status-bar)..... 

Thanks jnnnnn.  FLAG_NO_CLEAR was the one I couldn't find.  Damn!

Comment: notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.flags &= ~Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notification.flags &= ~Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;